# What does the notation $\left<\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\theta},\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\theta}\right>$ mean in differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to understand the relation between the metric tensor and the tangent space. I saw this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527765/how-does-a-metric-tensor-describe-geometry-on-a-manifold), which is very helpful, but it included a notation with which I'm unfamiliar:
$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}\left<\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\theta},\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\theta}\right>&\left<\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\theta},\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\varphi}\right>\\\left<\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\varphi},\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\theta}\right>&\left<\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\varphi},\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\varphi}\right>\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\sin^{2}\theta\end{pmatrix}$$
Would someone please explain exactly how to perform the operation:$$\left<\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\theta},\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial\theta}\right>$$I understand the partial derivatives, but not the comma inside the angle brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the inner product / dot product between the vector of partial derivatives given in the post.